# Power Automate Request Input from Dynamic Person

Tags: power-automate

I have a sharepoint list that is supposed to represent an approval flow for requesting new hires. Relevant items:

- Class size
- Date
- Manager
- Location
- Start time
- Approver 1
- Approver 2
- Approval Status

I have some options on designing the business flow, but right now with existing systems and meetings in place, it would be optimal to initiate the process with the first three items known, the location and start time to be filled in by whomever the manager is, and then the approval process to be initiated.

I have basically got the flows figured out in Power Automate except for manager filling in the missing information. The only thing I have figured out is to send a link to the sharepoint list, which exposes all of the columns to being edited, where the preference would be to have some read only and some editable. Is there any other way around this?

I think in an ideal situation some sort of form would be presented to the manager with read only values and the editable portions.

Comment: You using Teams?

Comment: @Skin Teams is available but I wasn't planning on it being part of the process. Not all our managers use it regularly.

Comment: It's a nice way to present the users with a prompt to enter information.  I'd suggest looking into it because it, I think, is your best option within the sphere of Microsoft products.

Comment: I think that's going to be a no-go to require our entire management staff to use teams for this process. Right now I am researching using the Power Apps Canvas feature to create a custom form, but I'm beating my head against a wall right now.

Comment: Yeah, that’d be a harder way. Do the management staff use any other Teams like tools? Like Slack maybe? What other O365 tools do they use?

Comment: Excel and Outlook are really the only tools we can count on, or any tool that can be accessed with a url sent via email. Mostly these guys are out in the field with technicians and supervisors, meeting with customers, etc. I could probably get them access to SQL Server db and replace the List with a table (which actually simplifies some of this, since our forecasting tool is SQL Server based), but again their interface would need to be a simple form they can click on from their email and modify the exact 1 record that needs their attention, and they wouldn't even know they are modifying a db.

Comment: What a shame that Teams isn't prominent because obviously 1) that works on a mobile device really well and 2) using adaptive cards, you could capture the relevant information and then update the SP list items as needed.  Now having said that, this could be an option for you ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/outlook

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253044/discussion-between-tristen-hannah-and-skin).